# Different types of asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

How is an asynchronous function such as `fs.readFile` written such that it is asynchronous but different from a function decorated with the `async` keyword? Does an `async` function always return a promise?

The following works:

```
const Area = async (L, B) => L * B;

Area(5, 4).then(
  a => console.log("Area is " + a)
);
```

However, a function like `fs.readFile` after invocation will result in an undefined value.

When using a function from a third-party library, is there a way to tell that a function is asynchronous other than from its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

[`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) implements asynchronousness through a callback, it returns nothing.

By contrast, [`fsPromises.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) implements asynchronousness by returning a promise.

The callback flavor of asynchronousness can be converted into the promise flavor with the [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) function.

The `async` prefix must be applied to a function if the code in the function body makes use of the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword. A function with that prefix always returns a promise (like your `Area`), but promise-returning functions are possible without the `async` prefix, for example:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Whether a function is asynchronous, and if so whether it uses the callback or promise flavor should be documented. If that is not the case, you can only try out its behavior. Note that a function could have several callbacks, and perhaps also return a promise. There are more types of asynchronous behavior than just the one enabled by `async`.

Comment: Are you able to shed light on how a function like `fs.readFile` is able to run asynchronously, ie the next instruction that is executed is the one after the invocation location rather than the first instruction in the function body?

Comment: Asynchronousness cannot be implemented by Javascript means, it happens inside the Javascript engine (written in C, for example).